# Can a sequence that does not store terms report Spliterator.ORDERED?

Tags: java, spliterator

I'm creating a class designed to study Collatz sequences that have arbitrarily large initial terms. Because of the size of the terms and the length of the resulting sequences, the terms of a given sequence are not stored in its corresponding instance, but can be iterated over.

Of course, the generating function returns the same terms in the same order for each traversal of a sequence, so it is technically ordered. However, I saw this in the documentation for `Spliterator.ORDERED`:

```
"Encounter order is guaranteed to be ascending index order for any List."
```

I have no way of defining the encounter order for a sequence explicitly in that fashion, only that it exists. Can I still report `Spliterator.ORDERED`?

NOTE: I am not implementing `List`. I just used the above quote as an example of the sort of explicit ordering definition I cannot provide.

Comment: You're not implementing `List`, are you?

Comment: No, I'm just using that quote to help describe my problem. I can see how that was a bit ambiguous; I apologize.

Comment: But that quote doesn't pertain to you. Just make sure you're following the contract: *Characteristic value signifying that an encounter order is defined for elements. If so, this Spliterator guarantees that method trySplit() splits a strict prefix of elements, that method tryAdvance(java.util.function.Consumer<? super T>) steps by one element in prefix order, and that forEachRemaining(java.util.function.Consumer<? super T>) performs actions in encounter order.* Your quote is just an example of how that applies to a `List`.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense.  I'm just overanalyzing things, as I am wont to do.